# Writing HTML in Java and send it through ajax

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, ajax

I want to able to write the html in Java and send it to ajax instead of getting the xml from java and looping in jQuery to create the html.
The reason why I want to do that is there are a lot of photos(could be 1000) to display for each ajax call so displaying them in jQuery will take ages.

the code for the ajax, I was writing the code for getting data with xml:

```
jQuery(".accordionclick").click(function() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "getPhotos",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: {
            bpID: jQuery("#ID").val(),
            password: jQuery('#password').val(),
            className: jQuery(this).attr("title")
        },
        success: function(xmlResponse) {
            var photos = (jQuery("Photo", xmlResponse).map(
                function() {
                    return {
                        imageLocation: jQuery(
                            "imageLocation",
                            this).text(),
                        id: jQuery("photoID", this)
                            .text(),
                        BII: jQuery("BII", this).text(),
                        jID: jQuery("jID", this).text(),
                        cName: jQuery("cName", this)
                            .text(),
                    };
                }));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. Did you mean the JAVA programming language, e.g. `getPhotos` is written in JAVA? Show the JAVA then

Comment: I very much doubt that performance will be greatly improved by html being returned in an XHR. Updating the DOM will still be a problem. Dealing with 1000's of entries you would be better off using some incremental scrolling solution (the user will never see all of the photos at once anyway), keeping the DOM nice and small.

Comment: @marthursson Thanks for your comment I will try to do that